# Why does AC voltage across doorbell chime drop to zero?

Tags: voltage

Two wires are exposed next to my doorbell chime. One comes from one terminal of the transformer and one comes from the doorbell pushbutton.

When I measure the voltage across the wires I see 22 VAC. However, when I connect the wires to the chime the voltage drops to 0. This is very confusing to me…

I’m assuming that the chime is some sort of a coil. My understanding is that with AC current (unlike in DC) a coil does NOT act like a short. So I expected a non-zero voltage drop across it.

Comment: Please draw a schematic and think for a while about KVL both when the button in pressed versus released.

Comment: @winny Not to disparage the OP but do you think the question would have been asked if OP knew KVL?

Comment: @JYelton updated my question.

Comment: @JYelton A so called leading question ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably a ghost voltage. This is because of the fact that although DC current has a lot of trouble travelling through very high resistance air gaps (such as those between your doorbell contacts) AC currents travel capacitances (which are also essentially just gaps) and therefore make it across your doorbell contacts more easily.

This current then flows across the gap between your two open wires. At this point, let's assume that the air gap impedances are so much higher than the impedance of the meter or coil that when you connect these series with it, the overall impedance does not change much. Given that the supply voltage is fixed, this means that the current flowing more or less remains constant. So let's assume that AC current flowing across the capacitive gap is constant from this point on.

Your multimeter was probably designed to be high impedance to load down the signal as little as possible (i.e. draw as little current possible from the circuit being measured in order to minimize the influence on the voltage measurement).

So when you connect the multimeter across the open wires, you replaced that airgap with your multimeter's input impedance which is lower than that of the air gap, but still high enough that the tiny AC currents (remember, it's constant current) could develop a measurable voltage drop across that impedance.

Then when you connected coil up, you again replaced that impedance with a very low impedance. This impedance is low enough that the same tiny AC current could not produce a voltage high enough to be measured.

Some meters are designed to be lower impedance to reproduce this effect to prevent ghost voltages from being measured. The price that is paid for this is these low impedance meters can't be used to accurately make measurements in more sensitive (high impedance) circuits.

In short:

1. A constant current flows in the circuit via the capacitive currents
   across the doorbell contacts.
2. Your multimeter, by design, has a high enough input impedance to produce a measurable voltage across it when the small capacitive current flows through it.
3. Conversely the coil impedance is very low so when the small capacitive current flows through it there is not enough of a voltage drop produced to be measurable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I’m unsure how it answers my question though. The above explanation makes sense to me. However, why is it that when I connect to wires to the chime and measure it from there (on the screws) I see 0 V?

Comment: @Kam I rewrote considerable parts of the answer to focus less on the low impedance meter and more on the coil. Please re-read.

Comment: Some doorbell buttons have lights in them, too, which also increases the "leakage" current.